# jboss.deployment.unit (missing)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, wildfly

I've tried to add [Vaadin ConfirmBox](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/confirmdialog) to my Java Project, I added the dependencies direct to pom.xml, then I became,

```
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ZertifizierungFasade.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ZertifizierungFasade.VIEW."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.ZertifizierungFasade".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ZertifizierungFasade.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ZertifizierungFasade.WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ZertifizierungFasade.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ZertifizierungFasade.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ZertifizierungFasade.WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ZertifizierungFasade.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ZertifizierungFasade.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.vaadin.cdi.internal.ContextDeployer".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.vaadin.cdi.internal.ContextDeployer".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.vaadin.cdi.internal.ContextDeployer".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.vaadin.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.vaadin.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.vaadin.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.vaadin.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.vaadin.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport$CometListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport$CometListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport$CometListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport$CometListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport$CometListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.peimari.dawn.CdnFonts".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.peimari.dawn.CdnFonts".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.peimari.dawn.CdnFonts".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.peimari.dawn.CdnFonts".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.peimari.dawn.CdnFonts".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".ee.ComponentRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.HonorarKraftFasade.START, service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.VertragsgruppeFasade.START, service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.BescheidartFasade.START, service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.SchulartFasade.START, WFLYCTL0208: ... and 48 more ] 
  service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformation (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.BetreuungskostenstellenFasade.START, service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.HonorarKraftFasade.START, service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.VertragsgruppeFasade.START, service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.BescheidartFasade.START, WFLYCTL0208: ... and 39 more ] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.AWOVertragsPartnerFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.AWOVertragsPartnerFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.AbrechnungsartFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.AbrechnungsartFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.BetreuungskostenstellenFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.BetreuungskostenstellenFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.BetreuungsleistungFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.BetreuungsleistungFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.ElternteilFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ElternteilFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.FortbildungFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.FortbildungFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.FunktionFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.FunktionFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.HonorarKraftFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.HonorarKraftFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.HonorarVertragspartnerFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.HonorarVertragspartnerFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.HonorarvertragFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.HonorarvertragFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.KindFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.KindFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.MitarbeiterFortbildungFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.MitarbeiterFortbildungFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.MitarbeiteraufgabeFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.MitarbeiteraufgabeFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.MitarbeitereinsatzFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.MitarbeitereinsatzFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.NotizenFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.NotizenFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.OGSVertragFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.OGSVertragFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.PersonFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.PersonFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.PersonenzertifizierungFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.PersonenzertifizierungFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.QualifikationFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.QualifikationFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.SchulartFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.SchulartFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.SchuleFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.SchuleFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.SchuljahrFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.SchuljahrFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.SchulkostenFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.SchulkostenFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.StundenartFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.StundenartFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.VertragFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.VertragFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.VertragsgruppeFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.VertragsgruppeFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.VertragsvorlageFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.VertragsvorlageFasade.START] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."de.imagmbh.awo_rm.ogs1.data.service.ZertifizierungFasade".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ZertifizierungFasade.START] 
  service jboss.persistenceunit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#postgres" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.BetreuungskostenstellenFasade.START, service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.HonorarKraftFasade.START, service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.VertragsgruppeFasade.START, WFLYCTL0208: ... and 26 more ] 
  service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".codec (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".session (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service org.wildfly.request-controller.control-point."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService

09:09:29,124 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called ogs1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.dodeploy
```

then I removed the dependencies from POM.xml, but the problem isn't gone!

Does anyone have any suggestion or hint?

I'm a beginner with Java, Wildfly, DeltaSpike and ..., then if the Question isn't clear, tell me please to which point should I mention to make it more clear.
I've already searched on the Internet, so if the question is duplicated, it could be that the other posts couldn't help me.

Best Regards!

Comment: This is not the actual error, something was wrong and so your deployment can't be started. It would be better to put all your stacktrace in the question so that we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam It's all I could put there, I didn't have enough space to put all the stacktrace here.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't have your actual exceptions. It should be somewhere up in your log (before the place you found these messages). Also if you're just trying to run you original code again, it worth trying `mvn clean` to make sure nothing remains from your last failed build.

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam I did it too but didn't help. I found the problem but it wasn't in my Stacktrace().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Problem was, that in my Project after removing [Vaadin ConfirmDialog](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/confirmdialog), there was still,

```
import org.vaadin.dialogs.ConfirmDialog;
```

in my project, but there was no error message to tell that.